# how to handle duplicate tags in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

```
<system>
  <load><avg01>0.03</avg01><avg05>0.15</avg05><avg15>0.16</avg15></load>
  <cpu><user>7.4</user>
  <system>3.2</system>
  <wait>0.9</wait></cpu>
  <memory><percent>17.1</percent>
  <kilobyte>1220364</kilobyte></memory>
  <swap><percent>0.0</percent>
  <kilobyte>396</kilobyte></swap>
</system>
```

How to take the entire system tag in beautifulsoup and skip the intermediate ones. Note there is system tag inside outer system tag.

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=0.5)
result = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

for item in result.findAll('system'):
    print item

OUTOUT 
<system><load><avg01>0.03</avg01><avg05>0.10</avg05><avg15>0.13</avg15></load><cpu><user>7.7</user></cpu></system>
```

Also I want to get percent value, but there are many percent tags in the entire xml which gets pulled out.

Answer (score 0):

First, match only the outer one. After that you can loop through it to see the contents

```
>>> for item in soup.find('system'):
    print item


<load><avg01>0.03</avg01><avg05>0.15</avg05><avg15>0.16</avg15></load>


<cpu><user>7.4</user>
<system>3.2</system>
<wait>0.9</wait></cpu>


<memory><percent>17.1</percent>
<kilobyte>1220364</kilobyte></memory>


<swap><percent>0.0</percent>
<kilobyte>396</kilobyte></swap>
```

Comment: it stops at <system>
  <load><avg01>0.03</avg01><avg05>0.15</avg05><avg15>0.16</avg15></load>
  <cpu><user>7.4</user>

Comment: Are you using `findAll` instead of `find`?

Comment: it stops at 1st system

Comment: Nope. I have to find another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `soup.system`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<system>
  <load><avg01>0.03</avg01><avg05>0.15</avg05><avg15>0.16</avg15></load>
  <cpu><user>7.4</user>
  <system>3.2</system>
  <wait>0.9</wait></cpu>
  <memory><percent>17.1</percent>
  <kilobyte>1220364</kilobyte></memory>
  <swap><percent>0.0</percent>
  <kilobyte>396</kilobyte></swap>
</system>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup.system
```

This yields:

```
<system>
<load><avg01>0.03</avg01><avg05>0.15</avg05><avg15>0.16</avg15></load>
<cpu><user>7.4</user>
<system>3.2</system>
<wait>0.9</wait></cpu>
<memory><percent>17.1</percent>
<kilobyte>1220364</kilobyte></memory>
<swap><percent>0.0</percent>
<kilobyte>396</kilobyte></swap>
</system>
```